# How to change the size of specific letters of the same word in android

Tags: android, fonts, subscript

I recover chemical formula from a json file, and to write them in the good way (with number in subscript), I use this method:

```
String s = item.get(NAME);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == '2' || s.charAt(i) == '3' || s.charAt(i) == '4'
        || s.charAt(i) == '5' || s.charAt(i) == '6') {
    sb.append("<sub>").append(s.charAt(i)).append("</sub>");
    } else {
    sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
}

name.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
```

It works fine but the font size of the subscript letters is the same than those of the others. And I'd like it is smaller. **So is there a way to change the size of specific letters in a word ?**

**Thanks**

Comment: please post item.get(NAME) value so i can test and try it any that for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *[android.text.Html](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/Html.java)* (on GrepCode), you may use `<small>` for smaller text, as `<font>` only supports color and face attributes.

for example **H**<sub>2</sub>**O**

```
String s = "<b>H</b><small><sub>2</sub></small><b>O</b>";
```

Comment: Thanks, just that I wanted. Thus I simply change 'sb.append("<sub>").append(s.charAt(i)).append("</sub>");' to '  sb.append("<small><sub>").append(s.charAt(i))
   .append("</sub></small>");'

Comment: Hey try my updated Answer so its look more batter :) happy to help you

Comment: Sorry, but I don't like it :). Even if they have to be smaller, numbers have also to be visible. And on a phone, it will be difficult with capital letters in bold.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [AbsoluteSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan.html) to do this. E.g.:

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString(text);
span.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(14, true), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

`start` and `end` define the range of characters to change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<font size="number"><font>`, where number means the size of the text you want. The code will work in strings, I've tried it.